# Google Line Chart, refresh the datatable

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have a very classic Linechart, getting data from php script in JSON format.
However, I want to update that graph at regular interval.

```
var jsonData1 = $.ajax({ url:"./scripts/json_papp.php", dataType:"json", async:false }).responseText;
var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData1);
var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('papp_div'));
chart1.draw(data1, opt1);
setInterval("updatePAPP()", 6000);

function updatePAPP() {
// here I need to get again the data from the script and draw it again.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
function updatePAPP() {
    $.ajax({ url:"./scripts/json_papp.php", dataType:"json", async:false }).done(function(jsonData1) {
        var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData1);
        var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('papp_div'));
        chart1.draw(data1, opt1);
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, no error but the graph is not updated. I'm not sure that "overwriting" the actual graph by another one (new variables are local) is a good method. And making global my variables dont work too.

Comment: Maybe I should find a way to clear the datatable, put new data on it and redraw the graph. But nowhere there is a method to clear a datatable...

Comment: Ok, approved. My bad, messing some globals and local variables. I have changed the name inside updatPAPP() function to avoid confusion, and it's working. But I'm not sure that solution dont eat memory for the long term.

Comment: You don't necessary need the line with `var chart1 = ...` withing the functions, you can define it in a scope outside the function, however I doubt this is going to be too memory heavy. The data1 can be big depending on your data, but this is something you need to think of based on your specific use case. Basically consider if a refresh every x seconds is really required/helpful for the user.